# Is there a setting that will allow vim to remember the column it was on, even if traverses a line who's EOL is less?

Tags: vim, vi

Is there a setting that will allow vim to remember the column it was on, even if traverses a line who's EOL is less?

Consider the following lines:

```
foo bar
foo
foo bar
```

Say my cursor position is the underscore:

```
foo b_r
foo
foo bar
```

If I hit `jj`, the cursor ends up here:

```
foo bar
foo
fo_ bar
```

But I want it to remember where it is on line 1 and go there on line 3 since it's available.

```
foo bar
foo
foo b_r
```

EDIT: When I disable minibufexpl.vim, the problem goes away, so it's a problem with that plugin. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: Have you tried `set virtualedit=all`?

Comment: Yes, but that includes some stuff that I don't want, like having your cursor past EOL.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't? Vim tries to keep the cursor on the same column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should go to the same column by default. Have you tried starting Vim as

```
$ vim -N -u NONE
```

or

```
$ gvim -N -u NONE
```

and performing your experiment again?

One thing that can cause this behavior is a plugin that uses the CursorHold autocommand. If such an autocommand performs certain actions when it executes, it will cause your cursor to move as you describe. You can check for the existence of such autocommands with

```
:au CursorHold
```

Comment: [minibufexpl.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=159) is the culprit. Now to figure out what the problem is...

Comment: I wrote a plugin that used the CursorHold autocommand event and had that problem with the cursor column. Vim resets the remembered cursor column to the current cursor column whenever an option is set, so I changed the code invoked by the CursorHold event to set options only when necessary. The minibufexpl plugin might have the same issues.